# Excessive brake dust and vibration / noise

Tags: brakes, nissan

Had brakes done about 3000 miles ago.  They felt tight at the beginning.  For the last week, brakes make a 'droning' noise and vibrate when applying brakes and both front wheel covers are completely covered in brake dust.

Comment: It is relatively normal for front wheels to be covered in brake dust. Were the previous brakes original? I ask because sometimes a shop will install pads with softer materials than the originals and this will generate more dust.

Comment: Since kipPoel mentioned that only the front wheel covers have break dust, I am assuming OP has disk breaks in the front, and drum breaks in the rear. (If drum breaks produce dust, the dust has no way of escaping the drum.)

Comment: When you say "vibrate", are you *hearing* them vibrate, or is the car lurching on-and-off when you apply the breaks?

Comment: Also, when you had the brakes done, did they replace only the pads, or the pads AND rotors? Because if they only replaced the pads, you *might* be able to stop the brake dust by installing OEM pads next time you have them changed.

Comment: I'd disagree that, after 3000 miles, anything other than race brakes would cause the wheels to be **completely covered** in brake dust, and based on the question, this isn't typical for OP's car. Possibly installed the wrong pad (too thick) which can explain the excessive dust as well as the vibration due to warpage.

Answer (score 0):

Brake dust is typical after 3000 miles. You can get low dust brake pads, but they will have trade-offs in brake feel or pad longevity.

Low pitch groaning noises are typically vibrations resulting from contact between the brake pad and brake caliper piston. There are products (ie 'Disc Brake Quiet') that are intended to be applied to the back of the brake pad (between the pad and piston) to absorb this vibration before it manifests as that annoying noise. If that's not it, you may want to have your mechanic re-bed the new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear, what is the question .Brake pads make different amounts of dust. "Organic " pads make the least, I have over 80,000 on some and have never seen dust. I had a 2004 Nissan Titan , it made a lot of dust. The dealer replaced the pads at 30,000 at no charge and they did not make dust any more ( drove it to 130,000 miles).